# how do you compare a param to every item in an array in rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a codes model and I basically have a form which should authenticate simply to every code recorded so my controller is:

```
def cancel_sale

  @codes = Code.find(:all)

  @codes.each do |c|
    @code = c.name
  end

  if params[:auth] && params[:auth] == @code

    something 

  else 

    @mensaje_de_salida = "wrong auth code"

  end

end
```

I know it's bad, at this moment it only authenticates to the last recorded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
def cancel_sale

  @codes = Code.find(:all)

  if params[:auth] && @codes.include?(params[:auth])
    #something
  else 
    @mensaje_de_salida = "wrong auth code"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Gabe's method is correct as well if you actually want to use  @codes for another purpose otherwise no need to retreive all the codes.

```
@codes = lambda { Code.find(:all, :conditions => ["auth = ?", params[:auth] ] ) }

if params[:auth] && !(@codes.call.empty?)
   #something
else
   #nothing
end
```